# I have a loop that calls ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion. How can I force a wait on that?

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

As the title says, I'm doing a CopySubresourceRegion in a loop, and at some point in there I need to force a wait until it completes.  From MSDN's documenation, it looks like I can call `ID3D11DeviceContext::Flush`, then `ID3D11DeviceContext::GetData` on an event Query created by `ID3D11Device::CreateQuery` with `D3D11_QUERY_EVENT`.

I've tried that, and it SEEMS to be working on my tests so far, but there are things I'm uncertain about.

1. Would it work correctly if I called `CreateQuery` just once before the loop begins and use that query repeatedly with each `GetData` call?
2. Should I destroy the query after creating it to prevent leaking queries?  There doesn't seem to be `DestroyQuery` method, so maybe call free on my `ID3D11Query*`?
3. If I can a call to either `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` or Unmap before I need to wait on the copy to finish, do I still need Flush?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an explicit wait for completion ? D3D11 is shielded internally for life duration an in-flight usage already. If you call `Map`, the system make sure to wait for completion for you.

Usually it is the opposite behavior we desire, to be able to query for completion in a non blocking way to know when it is safe to call `Map`, by using Queries.

For 2. Queries are like any other resources in D3D11, you destroy them by calling `Release` and you can reuse them, create a pool of queries, mark them used when used, then mark them available again once you were able to collect the data with `GetData`